# trouble with bash script setting up params for 'find' utility

Tags: bash, find, wildcard

The basic problem here is that I want to use a script to simplify making the 'find' utility skip a certain troublesome directory.

Bash scripting is not my strong suite. I'm stuck on how to get a quoted wildcard file specification on the command line into the script and from there into a find command unscathed. Seems like bash likes to rip quotes off things and expand words containing wild cards into lists of words, which is normally great, but when I try to evaluate 'find' inside a script, this command line cookery happens *twice*, with undesirable results.

Now I'm going to give the gory details, b/c maybe someone will see what I'm really trying to do and say 'hey you know there's an easier way to do this altogether'. An end-run around the problem is fine with me.

so, the background -

On the machine in question, there is an automated backup system that archives about two dozen snapshots of certain directories, such as user's home directories and various project locations. So within my home directory I have ~/.backup/hourly.0, ~/.backup/hourly.1, etc etc through about hourly.12, and then nightly.1 through about nightly.12, so there's HUGE duplication. Ordinarily this is a nice safety net, until I want to 'find' something in my home directory.

For example, suppose I want to find all the *.foo files; the simple solution is issuing

```
find ~ -name "*.foo"
```

.. except that on this machine, find starts sifting through all those backup directories. Usually I'm not interested hits in the .backup directories. Searching them is slow, and for all I know they're network mounted and I'm melting someone's data closet. So the next evolution is doing something with a form like this

```
find ~ ! \( -name .backup -prune \) -a -name "*.foo"
```

.. which works, and isn't too bad if it only needs to be used once or twice. But it's easy to fat finger it, and gets annoying when it's needed several times in a row. So it seemed like a good idea to write a script to handle this. For lack of a more imaginative name, let's use 'findx'. The idea was to issue findx ~ -name "*.foo", and have 'findx' automatically translate this to the more complicated form. The first hack at the script looked like this

```
find $1 ! \( -name .backup -prune \) $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7
```

admittedly, this is terribly kludgey looking, and won't work for searches that have too many parameters. (If there's a way to specify 'all the parameters starting from the second one', I don't know it.) The find command's peculiar syntax seems to dictate splitting up $1 from the rest of the parameters, b/c the search root location has to go first, and the -prune and -print clauses don't work correctly if they're in reverse order, so -prune has to come before the (implicitly) printed stuff, leaving $2 $3 etc on the right. Anyway, it should have been sufficient for simple enough searches.

Well, this seemed to work ok for specific filenames, but wildcards brought it down. Seems that if, for example, I feed it

```
findx . -name "*stuff"
```

that bash *first* strips the quotes off *stuff before passing it into the script as one of the $ params. The find command that gets built then doesn't have quotes wrapping the wildcard; so when *that* gets executed, the shell then expands the * before exec'ing the find, which then chokes, b/c find wants the one word *stuff rather than the list it expands to. (evidently find likes to do its own wildcard expansion?)

So - is there a way to make this work? Is there some other way to omit searching a directory that isn't just so darned wordy, thereby obviating the motivation for a script? An alternative to find, that can do most of what find can do, e.g., -ctime, -type, -name, and so forth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If there's a way to specify 'all the parameters starting from the second one', I don't know it.

It's `"${@:2}"`, as in:

```
find "$1" ! \( -name .backup -prune \) "${@:2}"
```

[The Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html) is a bit of a dense read, but it does describe this behavior, if you know where to look. Specifically, in §3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion, in the description of `${parameter:offset}` and `${parameter:offset:length}`, it mentions that "If *parameter* is ‘@’, the result is *length* positional parameters beginning at *offset*", and later that "Substring indexing is zero-based unless the positional parameters are used, in which case the indexing starts at 1 by default."

Comment: Also, note that having the parameter references in double-quotes should solve the wildcard misbehavior (and handle spaces and parameters, and...), so as far as I can see this should fully solve both problems.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but looking at thd [ABS Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html), I see a couple of interesting things.

> $@
>
> Same as $*, but each parameter is a quoted string, that is, the parameters are passed on intact, without interpretation or expansion. This means, among other things, that each parameter in the argument list is seen as a separate word.

This could be useful with the wildcard expansion problem.

> Following a shift, the $@ holds the remaining command-line parameters, lacking the previous $1, which was lost.

And this with the way to specify all parameters starting from the second one.

I hope this helps.

Comment: ok, sounds enticing, but one question - what's a "shift"? I figured there ought to be a way to pull the params one at a time and a way to refer to whatever's left, and this sounds like that. Just don't know what the mechanism is to remove the 1st from the list.

Comment: You'll find information about `shift` in the [Bash Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html).

Comment: in case anyone happens by here in future, I'll make it easy. 'shift' is just a command. If you say 'shift 1', then all the arguments slide left one place; the value formerly at $2 is found at $1, etc.